# Ajuda com array de objetos

Tags: php

Há um jeito de adicionar, sem ser manualmente, um array indexado? Por exemplo:

```
$arrayNomeBDs[0] = array (
    "nome_tabela" => "TabelaDeNome1",
    "db-tb-name" => "table_name_bd1"
);
$arrayNomeBDs[1] = array (
    "nome_tabela" => "TabelaDeNome1",
    "db-table-name" => "table_name_bd2"
);
```

Se eu colocar na próxima iteração como `index = 3`, vai dar erro

```
$arrayNomeBDs[3] = array (
    "nome_tabela" => "TabelaDeNome1",
    "db-tb-name" => "table_name_bd2"
);
```

Esse é o meu `for` para percorrer:

**vai dar erro se eu colocar o index = 3 se eu seguir o exemplo anterior:**

```
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($arrayBDs);$i++){
    var_dump($arrayBDs[$i]['nome_tabela']);
    if($arrayBDs[$i]['nome_tabela'] === $BD_Escolhido){
        return $arrayBDs[$i]['db-tb-name'];
    }
}
```

Futuramente vai dar trabalho retirar um banco da array e colocar manualmente os index em ordem tudo de novo, como eu tenho 40 bancos para criar (o tempo todo entra um banco novo ou é retirado um ou mais), então mais pra frente vai dar trabalho fazer a manutenção.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você vai ficar removendo e adicionando itens, correto? Se sim, já pensou em usar uma lista encadeada no lugar de um array?

Comment: não pensei em usar, essa array contém várias tabelas que vão mudar em tempo em tempo, no front a pessoa escolhe o nome do banco (coloquei um valor genérico), depois eu envio esse nome pro php, lá eu procuro por esse nome e retorno o nome da tabela do banco de dados. fiz isso pro usuário não ter acesso ao nome do banco de dados.

Comment: Pela descrição do seu problema acho que você poderia usar uma lista ao invés do array, ela vai resolver o principal problema que você descreveu: "futuramente vai dar trabalho retirar um banco da array e colocar manualmente os index em ordem tudo de novo". Com uma lista você não precisa se preocupar em reordenar o index, ela faz isso automaticamente.

Comment: como faço isso em php? uma lista de objetos? rsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você deve verificar se um indice existe antes de compara-lo. Evitando o erro:

```
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($arrayBDs);$i++){
    var_dump($arrayBDs[$i]['nome_tabela']);
    if(isset($arrayBDs[$i]['nome_tabela']) && $arrayBDs[$i]['nome_tabela'] === $BD_Escolhido){
        return $arrayBDs[$i]['db-tb-name'];
    }
}
```

Caso você queira criar array's sem definir um indice, você pode fazer assim:

```
$arrayNomeBDs = array();
$arrayNomeBDs[] = array (
    "nome_tabela" => "TabelaDeNome1",
    "db-tb-name" => "table_name_bd1"
);
$arrayNomeBDs[] = array (
    "nome_tabela" => "TabelaDeNome1",
    "db-table-name" => "table_name_bd2"
);
```